# LWC quick action not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, quickaction, summer-21

I am trying the new summer 21 feature: LWC from quick action. I am trying this on my developer edition, already updated to summer 21 version.

But with a very simple code, the modal is not opening and I get and error that I don't understand.

Html:

```
<template> 
   Test quick action
</template>
```

js:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
 
export default class TestQuickAction extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("recordId", this.recordId);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="urn:metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com" fqn="testQuickAction">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>Action</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Console Error:

```
[LWC QUICK ACTION]s.invoke is not a function
handleClick @   executorLwcHeadless.js:1
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create the screen action then use action type as `ScreenAction`. `Action` can be used only for headless actions. For headless action, you need to define the `@api invoke(){...}` function in your component.

Just change the action type inside the target config from your component's meta XML.

```
<actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
```

Comment: FYI - When i tried this it says "Cannot change the type of the existing Lightning Web Component action."

Comment: @CodeMonger did you try removing the references of the components?

Comment: @CodeMonger I have it too. Deletion of component and re-creation worked

Comment: Had to delete from org and redeploy from vscode.

Comment: I had to delete the action AND the LWC, then redeploy the LWC to bypass the "cannot change..." error